# Java: 2D char array search

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm doing a word search program and I think I'm close to figuring it out, but I still have a few problems. My program reads in a text file made up of rows and columns of letters and turns it into a 2d char array into a separate class. This is my actual word search class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordSearch
{
    private char[][] array;
    private String targetWord;
    private int rowLocation;
    private int colLocation;

    public WordSearch(char[][] inArray)
    {
        array = inArray;
    }

    public void play()
    {
        do{
            for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++)
                {
                    System.out.print(array[row][col]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            System.out.println();
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
            System.out.println("What word would you like to search for? Type end to quit: ");
            targetWord = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Typed in: " + targetWord);
            System.out.println();

            compareFirst(targetWord);
        } while (!targetWord.equals("end"));

    }

    public void compareFirst(String inWord)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++)
            {
                if(array[row][col] == inWord.charAt(0))
                {

                    rowLocation = row;
                    colLocation = col;

                    suspectAnalysis();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void suspectAnalysis()
    {
        checkRight();
        checkDown();
        checkDiagonal();
    }


    public void checkRight()
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < (targetWord.length()); i++)
        {
            if(colLocation + i > array[0].length - 1)
            {
                return;
            }

            else if(array[rowLocation][colLocation + i] != targetWord.charAt(i))
            {
               return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(targetWord + " found horizontally at row " + rowLocation + " and column " + colLocation);
        System.out.println();

        return;

    }


    public void checkDown()
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < (targetWord.length()); i++)
        {
            if(rowLocation + i > array.length - 1 && colLocation + i > array[0].length - 1)
            {
                return;
            }
            else if(array[rowLocation + i][colLocation] != targetWord.charAt(i))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(targetWord + " found vertically at row " + rowLocation + " and column " + colLocation);
        System.out.println();          
    }

    public void checkDiagonal()
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < (targetWord.length()); i++)
        {
            if(colLocation + i > array[0].length - 1 || rowLocation + i > array.length - 1)
            {
                return;
            }

            else if(array[rowLocation + i][colLocation + i] != targetWord.charAt(i))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(targetWord + " found diagonally at row " + rowLocation + " and column " + colLocation);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

So, it usually manages to find words in all three directions, but also "finds" words when it finds the first letter and any other letter after it. It also finds the word "end", which is supposed to terminate the do-while loop, so it just ends up being an infinite loop. Sometimes even if a word can be found both horizontally and vertically, the program only says it's found horizontally. Also, in some cases it prints out where the word was found two times.

Any help figuring out what's wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your terminating string is `quit`, not `end`. In addition, the reason why it finds erroneous words is because you accept a targetWord even if only one character matches.

```
public void checkRight()
{
    for(int i = 1; i < (targetWord.length()); i++)
    {
        if(colLocation + i > array.length - 1)
        {
            return;
        }

        else if(array[rowLocation][colLocation + i] == targetWord.charAt(i))
        {
            System.out.println(targetWord + " found horizontally at row " + rowLocation + " and column " + colLocation);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

That is, if `array[rowLocation][colLocation+i] == targetWord.charAt(i)`, then you automatically accept this word. This is not correct, because you have to check that all letters match at every position.

Comment: Thank you, I changed my code and now it checks if a character at a certain position is not equal to `targetWord.charAt(i)` and terminates the loop with a return statement . I moved the statement that prints the location of the found word to the outside the for loop so it now executes only if the for loop hasn't been terminated. I changed the do-while loop's condition to `while (!targetWord.equals("end"));`.

Comment: The right and diagonal methods work perfectly when tested alone or together, but the 'checkDown' method is executing even if I type end and gives back an out of bounds error. Any idea on how to fix this? I'll update my code so you can see the changes better

Answer (score 0):

Modified it little bit to handle all conditions.

```
public class WordSearch
{


    public static void compareFirst(char array[][], String targetWord)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++)
            {
                if(array[row][col] == targetWord.charAt(0))
                {

                    suspectAnalysis(array, row, col, targetWord);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void suspectAnalysis(char array[][], int rowLocation, int colLocation, String targetWord)
    {
        checkRight(array, rowLocation, colLocation, targetWord);
        checkDown(array, rowLocation,  colLocation,  targetWord);
        checkDiagonal(array, rowLocation,  colLocation, targetWord);
    }


    public static void checkRight(char array[][], int rowLocation, int colLocation, String targetWord)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < (targetWord.length()); i++)
        {
            if(colLocation + i > array[0].length - 1)
            {
                return;
            }

            else if(array[rowLocation][colLocation + i] != targetWord.charAt(i))
            {
               return;
            }
            
        }
        System.out.println(targetWord + " found horizontally at row " + rowLocation + " and column " + colLocation);
        System.out.println();

        return;

    }


    public static void checkDown(char array[][],int rowLocation, int colLocation, String targetWord)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < (targetWord.length()); i++)
        {
            if(rowLocation + i >= array.length - 1)
            {
                return;
            }
            else if(array[rowLocation + i][colLocation] != targetWord.charAt(i))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(targetWord + " found vertically at row " + rowLocation + " and column " + colLocation);
        System.out.println();          
    }

    public static void checkDiagonal(char array[][], int rowLocation, int colLocation, String targetWord)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < (targetWord.length()); i++)
        {
            if(colLocation + i > array[0].length - 1 || rowLocation + i > array.length - 1)
            {
                return;
            }

            else if(array[rowLocation + i][colLocation + i] != targetWord.charAt(i))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(targetWord + " found diagonally at row " + rowLocation + " and column " + colLocation);
        System.out.println();
    }
    


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        

        char array [][] = {
                {'D',   'D' ,   'D',    'O' ,   'G'},
                {'C',   'O',    'G',    'O',    'D'},
                {'C',   'A',    'G',    'K',    'M'},
                {'Z',   'A',    'T',    'Y',    'L'},
                {'X',   'C',    'T',    'N',    'N'}
            };
         
         

          compareFirst(array, "DDOG");
        
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).